# add space between arabic and english word by regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to add a space between Arabic/Farsi and English words in my text.
It should be with regular expression in python.

for example:

```
input: "علیAli"          output: "علی Ali"
input: "علیAliرضا"       output: "علی Ali رضا" 
input: "AliعلیRezaرضا"   output: "Ali علی Reza رضا"
```

and what ever like them.

Comment: does it have to be regex? why use regex?

Comment: I need it in my code. It should be in regular expression mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `re.sub` likes the following in python 3:

```
rx = r'[a-zA-Z]+'
output = re.sub(rx, r' \g<0> ', input)
```

Comment: @Yilmazam my pleasure. You can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regular expression , I think this can be done by comparing unicodes. I tried to code the same but didn't know how to again split /r/n to get the required output. This code might be useful for some one.

```
import codecs,string
def detect_language(character):
    maxchar = max(character)
    if u'\u0041' <= maxchar <= u'\u007a':
        return 'eng'

with codecs.open('letters.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    eng_list = []
    eng_var =0
    arab_list = []
    arab_var=0
    input = f.read()
    for i in input:
        isEng = detect_language(i)
        if isEng == "eng":
            eng_list.append(i)
            eng_var = eng_var + 1
        elif '\n' in i or '\r' in i:
            eng_list.append(i)
            arab_list.append(i)

        else:
            arab_list.append(i)
            arab_var =arab_var +1
temp = str(eng_list)
temp1 = temp.encode('ascii','ignore')
```